# Django forms date.today() doesn't return the right date in the morning

Tags: django, forms, date

I have a form with :

```
class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
input_type = "date"

Date = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput(),initial=datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

However I have the right date only after ~ 10AM, before I have the date of yeasterday.
Any idea of what I miss ?

Thanks

Comment: The initial is simply evaluated *once* and then each time uses that value.

Comment: my goal is when the user open the form, the date is set to today and not yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: @MichalS: that is not part of `initial`. You need to specify the format: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#date-format

Answer (score 0):

The `intial` is only evaluated *once* when you start the server. So as long as the server is not restarted, it will keep the date of the restart.

You can pass a callable to the function:

```
class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'

# …

date = forms.DateField(
    widget=DateInput(),
    initial=datetime.date.today
)
```

Note that this can be *timezone* sensitive. If you want a different timezone, you can define a function to provide the correct date:

```
from django.utils import timezone
from pytz

utc_14 = pytz.timezone('Pacific/Tongatapu')

def initial_date():
    return utc_14.normalize(timezone.now()).date()

…

date = forms.DateField(
    widget=DateInput(),
    initial=initial_date
)
```

This will on this moment return `datetime.date(2020, 7, 3)`, since right now in *Tongatapu* it is already July 3rd.

The format is not by the `initial` parameter. You need to use settings like the [**`DATE_FORMAT`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#date-format) and  [**`DATE_INPUT_FORMAT`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#date-input-format) for that. It furthermore also depends on *localization* settings.